# Python receive only one variable from a tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, select

`rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([Server] + open_client_sockets, [], [])`

I understand this code above inserts readable files to readlist, writeable files to wlist, and exceptional files to xlist. but what if i want to only receive the rlist? I don't want python to create wlist and xlist variables.

is something like `rlist, [], [] = select.select([Server] + open_client_sockets, [],[])` possible?

Comment: the convention is to use underscore `_` for unwanted values, or take the first by index with `result[0]`

Answer (score 2):

With Python 3, you can simply do:

```
rlist, *_ = select.select([Server] + open_client_sockets, [],[])
```

Since what you're using is Python 2, you can achieve the same with:

```
rlist, _, _ = select.select([Server] + open_client_sockets, [],[])
```

The above is called unpacking, and `_` is what we generally use to throw away data that we are not interested in.

Answer (score 1):

(The following assumes you have rejected using throwaway names like `_`, and really want to set *just* `rlist`.)

> I don't want python to create wlist and xlist variables.

Then don't let it :)

```
rlist = select.select([Server] + open_client_sockets, [], [])[0]
```

You can immediately index the anonymous triple returned by `select.select`, thereby never binding the rest of the return value to any name.

---

The standard objection to this is its poor readability; you see assignment to one name and the function being called, and it's easy to assume `rlist` will be the expected triple. The `[0]` can get lost at the end of the call.

One workaround is to use a helper function to move the "indexing" up front:

```
from operator import itemgetter

rlist = itemgetter(0)(select.select([Server] + open_client_sockets, [], []))
```

However, that's even less readable and really not the intended use-case for `itemgetter`.

---

Or, just add a second line of code

```
rlist = select.select([Server] + open_client_sockets, [], [])
rlist = rlist[0]
```

which delays the garbage collection of the other two objects returned by `select.select` ever so slightly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscores for tuple members you don't care about

```
rlist, _, _ = select.select([Server] + open_client_sockets, [], [])
```

Comment: Note that `_` is just a convention. You're actually assigning the value to a variable named `_`. One of the values will hang around because there's still a reference to it. Usually that's not an issue, but sometimes it is.

Comment: _ has another meaning when doing i18n, for example.

Comment: @progmatico um, `i18n`? Underscores don't have any special meaning in the language *Python*, but *can* be used as special variables in certain REPLs, like the default interpreter REPL and IPython...

Comment: @progmatico Only by convention; it is up to the user to explicitly create the alias `_ = gettext.gettext` if so desired.

Comment: " _ has another meaning when doing i18n, for example. " . Forget this, this is all about conventions, thanks for pointing that @chepner

Comment: @progmatico I had to look it up a few weeks ago; I also thought `_` was exposed by the `gettext` module itself.

Comment: Also,  I tend to prefer the use of `dummy`as it makes explicit it is to throw away.